# Ag-Grid Floating Filter server side

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-Grid free edition in which i am loading the datas from server side using pagination.I have added an floating filter to load datas from server based on the user input in a column.
I have tried to use the filter params when the user types a character it makes a server call and fetches the result.But instead of one call it makes n calls (Based on the number of datas available in the table) for every character. as well as once the resultant data is received the filtered text gets disappears.

```
{
headerName: 'Action',
field: 'action',
filterParams: {
    filterOptions: ['contains'],
    applyButton: false,
    resetButton: false,
    debounceMs: 2000,
    textCustomComparator: (filter, value, filterText) => {
    const filteredText = filterText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + filterText.slice(1);
    if (filteredText) {
        this.searchData(filteredText);
        console.log('filterText', filterText);
    } else {
        console.log('else block got called');
    }
    },
},
suppressMenu: true,
floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true }
```

},

Server Call:

```
 searchData(text: string) {
  this.auditService.getColumnSearch(text).pipe(first()).subscribe((searchDatas: any) => {
    this.rowData = searchDatas.docs;
    this.pagination = searchDatas.items;
    this.paginationPages = searchDatas.pages;
  });
}
```

I would like to know whether anyone has tried using column filter in ag-grid with server side and  how you have done it.

Comment: Do you mean for each key keydown, your searchData function is getting called ?

Comment: @Yogendra123 Yes for each key down searchData is getting called

Comment: this is the expected behaviour, what are you expecting here as per your requirement ?